# owl carousal navigation coming in same line in html

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel, owl-carousel

i have a ready made owl carousal slider in which the images slide automatically and there is a navigation at the top, now i have added tow more sliders of the same. but the problem is the navigation arrows are coming in one line instead of its corresponding sliders like below:

[image]

```html
<div class="owl-carousel" data-autoplay="true" data-items="1" data-sm-items="2" data-lg-items="3" data-xl-items="4" data-margin="30" data-mouse-drag="false" data-navigation-class="#owl-custom-nav-1">
```

i have tried using margin top and padding and all, but none of it is working, can anyone please tell mw how to make the arrows above its corresponding sliders. thanks

Comment: can you please add full snippet and make sure we can run and see how it's looking

Comment: @user6250770 my full code is alot, i have posted the datanavigation code, that navigation is coming in same line as in the image i uploaded above,

Comment: you want multiple images(i.e tiles) in same slider side by side and on click left or right it should slide or only one single big images in each slider ?

Comment: @user6250770 no bro, i have 3 sections in which 3 sliders are there, but the arrows are coming above the first slider, and the ither two sliders doesnt have arrows above it

Comment: Then it is css issue.. you add a sperate custom class for other two slider arrows and add your style.. then you can achieve that

Comment: Can you come over anydesk application so that i can look into that and help you..

Comment: not connecting..password

Comment: it's not working.. i will do one thing.. i will post an answer with some basic UI and example.. you enhance yourself using that as reference

Comment: @user6250770 i will download anydesk wait

Comment: @user6250770 please send request 631 030 412

Comment: it's okay... check my answer as reference and work around with that

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#owl-demo, #owl-demo-1").each(function() {
       $(this).owlCarousel({
          items : 6, //10 items above 1000px browser width
          itemsDesktop : [1000,6], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
          itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // 3 items betweem 900px and 601px
          itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
          itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
        });
      });
      // Custom Navigation Events
      $(".next").click(function(){$(this).closest('.span12').find('.owl-carousel').trigger('owl.next');})
      $(".prev").click(function(){$(this).closest('.span12').find('.owl-carousel').trigger('owl.prev');})
    });
```

```css
    #owl-demo .item, #owl-demo-1 .item{
        background: #3fbf79;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        margin: 10px;
        color: #FFF;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 190px;
    }
    .customNavigation{
      text-align: center;
    }
    .customNavigation a{
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>2</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>3</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>5</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>6</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>7</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>8</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>9</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>10</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="customNavigation"> <a class="btn prev">Previous</a> <a class="btn next">Next</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="demo-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="owl-demo-1" class="owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>2</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>3</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>4</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>5</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>6</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>7</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>8</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>9</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>10</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="customNavigation"> <a class="btn prev">Previous</a> <a class="btn next">Next</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```